# How do I make two choice fields that will be saved as one value in the database in django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    eta = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want the eta to be saved as a CharField that will be inputed by the user via two fields:
one field for the measurement, for example: months, days, minutes etc.
and one field for the amount, for example: 1, 4, 10 etc...

at the end I would like to have the eta field be
'1 hour', '30 minutes', '2 weeks' etc...

I want the user to input the fields and then have the backend save them in to the right format.

can anyone help with how to do this?
or maybe if someone has an idea on how to do this in a better way.
I want to make an application that will detect when the ETA already passed and alert the user of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DateField for this functionality with:

```
eta = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

When you render this field using a Model Form, it will display a Date Input widget for the user to select a date when the 'eta' is expected.

The countdown to 'eta' should be done separately to storage of the expected date, perhaps with some JavaScript. I have linked some resources below.

Model field reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput

Countdown functionality:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

[How to add a countdown timer as a user field in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992298/how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-as-a-user-field-in-django)

[How to implement countdown timer in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603409/how-to-implement-countdown-timer-in-django)

Comment: The thing is, I want it to be reused. Like it's not a specific date. It's more so the amount of time a specific task should take. And then have django respond when that time was exceeded

Comment: @MesserOr Django's built in DateTimeField is perfect for what you are trying to achieve. When the user is creating a 'Task' instance, they will be able to set a date and time when the the task is expected to be complete. 
If the task is due in 30 minutes, they would simply select the same date, 30 minutes into the future. If it was due in 1 month, they would select 1 month in the future. 
Storing '1 month' as a CharField/TextInput is just going to overcomplicate things for you. 
[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput)

Comment: I see what you mean. The thing is that I'm trying to make so one user creates a task for multiple other users to use. But I want them to set the amount of time a task should take for everybody. See what I mean? Any idea on how to do this?